# Disable customer registration

Tags: password

I need to disable customer registration.

Default, if a customer selects '*registration*' in the top menu, a form appears with fields for first name, last name, email and password.

I added some fields to this form like company and telephone number, deleted the password fields and changed some texts to let the customer know he is applying for an account and will receive passwords after approval. So a mail has to be generated to inform us.

But when a customer fills out the form, he gets the message "*password can not be empty*"
What is the best and easiest way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is to make the passwords fields hidden and fill them with a random value. Just make sure it's the same for the password field and the confirmation field.

[See here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9472/146) some code that can be used. It is for hiding the password in the checkout section but it should be the same for registring.

Comment: Thank you so much! Had been searching for hours. It works, although customer gets to see his dashboard with the option to change his password, will try to find a way around this.

Comment: You can change the register controller and register the user as disabled and you can enable it from the backend later. But this is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks again! You are fast! Really appreciate it. Will look into it.