# Frontend Customer Creation - disable password

Tags: magento-1.8, customer

I need to remove the password/ confirm password fields from customer creation page, I´d tried to use this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/how-to-generate-random-password-for-new-customer-while-creating-account-in-magen?newreg=de021913bd064ede8f3f0b31be503388) as source trying to solve this by random genarate password and edited this files
`\theme\template\customer\form\register.phtml` and `\theme\template\persistant\customer\form\register.phtml`

and the fields are still showing up.

Any better way to do that or any other files that I should change it either?

**Edit:** Code-snippet as requested

```
<div class="fieldset">
    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Login Information') ?></h2>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <?php $password = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length = 7)?>

<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" value="<?php echo $password?>"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="hidden" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" value="<?php echo $password?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

I also had tryied to change the Title "Create Account" in these same pages and it´s not showing on frontend as well.

I thought about a template hint extension to see where Magento is calling this templates from, however I´m not finding any still active for 1.x versions.

Comment: can you please add your code for better understanding?

Comment: "I thought about a template hint extension to see where Magento is calling this templates from" -- go to `System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer`, switch to your view/website (left top drop down above the right sidebar menu), and set `Debug -> Template Path Hints` to yes. No need for any extension to see where your templates are coming from (probably solves the initial problem as well already?).

Answer (score 0):

Sure....

```
       <div class="fieldset">
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Login Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php $password = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length = 7)?>

<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" value="<?php echo $password?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="hidden" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" value="<?php echo $password?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

I also had tryied to change the Title "Create Account" in these same pages and it´s not showing on frontend as well.

I thought about a template hint extension to see where magento is calling this templates from,  however I´m not fiding any one still active for 1.x versions.